# Python 3.6: using Simpson's method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to integrate using Simpson's method for a set of data. I found that I can do the following as shown below: result=simps(velocity, time, dx=(1/60)). I want the spacing to be in seconds not minutes (hence 1/60) - but changing the value of dx doesn't change my result. How can I integrate with dx in seconds?

```
# import the necessary modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# reads the experimnetal data
a=np.loadtxt("VelvstUniform.txt")

# assigns the data columns
time=a[:,0]
velocity=a[:,1]

# graphs in the same figure Sunspots vs Year and LEO vs Year
plt.plot(time,velocity,markersize=10, color="green", marker="o", 
linestyle="-")
plt.xlabel("Time (min)", fontweight="bold", fontsize="large")
plt.ylabel("velocity (miles/hour)", fontweight="bold", fontsize="large", 
color="green")

from scipy.integrate import simps
result=simps(velocity, time, dx=(1/60))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something there:

`dx` changes the width of the integration chunks, but not their unit. In order to do that, you have to multiply your values with the your wished scaling factor. And I think you would rather want `time` in hours, because you measure your velocity in mph.

You can just change `result`; its current unit is min*mi/h, so you have to multiply with 1/60 to get the result in miles.

Comment: My mistake, yes I meant hours to minutes for dx.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks